# How cnidocytes work?

Tags: cell-biology

I have googled  for the structure of cnidocyte but images of google is unclear or complex .so please draw a simple understandable structure of cnidocyte .I know that cnidocyte works by osmosis but I don't know how exactly osmosis make cnidocyte to function .so please explain the mechanism of cnidocyte.

Answer (score 1):

A cnidocyte is a poison-loaded harpoon connected to a pressure plate, implemented at the microscale level in a cell. Something triggers the plate, the harpoon jets out. Simple enough.